# Disabling escape in FormHelper::postLink() breaks alert confirmation

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

When I try setting escape to false within a postlink helper, the JavaScript alert seems to break in Chrome, not sure why as I'm not getting any console errors, it just fires the action without an initial alert.

```
echo $this->Form->postLink('<i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete',
    array('controller' => 'documents', 'action' => 'delete', $document['id']),
    array('escape' => false),
    null, __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $document['file'])
);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Wrong number of arguments

By adding the `escape => false` option, you forgot to remove the placeholder `null` for the third argument. Because of this, you're now passing *five* arguments.

Remove the `null` and it should work;

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(
    // title
    '<i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete',

    // URL
    array('controller' => 'documents', 'action' => 'delete', $document['id']),

    // Options
    array('escape' => false),

    // confirmMessage
    __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $document['file'])
);
```

See the documentation; [`FormHelper::postLink()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::postLink)

Comment: The documentation actually only lists 3 parameters, making things even more confusing. As of 2.6 the 'confirmMessage' parameter is an option with the key 'confirm' so you would write: `array('escape' => false, 'confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $document['file']))`